# Type-safe usage of Java reflection in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, scala-cats

I am trying to use Java reflection to replace the value for an object's field at runtime, but in a type-safe way.

Let's assume we have the following object.

```scala
import cats.Eval

object Foo {
  val bar: Eval[Int] = Eval.later(throw new Exception)
}
```

We want to change the value for `Foo.bar` at runtime. We can easily define the following method using normal Java reflection:

```scala
import java.lang.reflect.Field

def usingJavaReflection[T](targetObject: AnyRef, fieldName: String)(newValue: T): Unit = {
  val field = targetObject.getClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
  field.setAccessible(true)
  field.set(targetObject, newValue)
}

// usage
usingJavaReflection(Foo, "bar")(Eval.now(42))
```

Now the question becomes: how to do that in a more type-safe way?

```scala
def usingJavaReflectionButTypesafe[T](field: T)(newValue: T): Unit = ???

// intended usage
usingJavaReflectionButTypesafe(Foo.bar)(Eval.now(42))
```

This means being able to do a few things:

1. `Foo.bar` should not be evaluated
2. Instead, `Foo.bar` should be broken down into a target object `Foo` and a field `"bar"`
3. The type for `Foo.bar` should be the same as for `newValue`

Bonus question: **If** this is possible, how to make it work for Scala 2.11 and 2.12 and 2.13. I just cannot wrap my head around which Scala macros techniques are safe to use in which versions of Scala, and how.

Comment: Runtime reflection is unsafe by nature on JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
def usingJavaReflectionButTypesafe[T](field: => T)(newValue: T): Unit = macro impl[T]

def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(field: c.Tree)(newValue: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  field match {
    case q"$expr.$tname" =>
      q"usingJavaReflection($expr, ${tname.toString})($newValue)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work well with Scala 2.13 for top-level objects, as it seems that they are now compiled into static fields: `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final int field ammonite.$sess.cmd4$Foo$Bar$.baz to java.lang.Integer`.

We would need a way to discriminate between normal objects and top-level ones with static fields.

Comment: @betehess Try to change `val` to `var`.

Comment: I would like to avoid `var` altogether. Also, it would be nice to be able to reject `def` and `lazy val` as well.